# How hide div if another div is open use javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have div like this use javascript :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnmsg-1").click(function(){
        $(".msgid-1").show();
    });
    $("#btnmsg-2").click(function(){
        $(".msgid-2").show();
    });
    $("#btnmsg-3").click(function(){
        $(".msgid-3").show();
    });
    $("#btnmsg-4").click(function(){
        $(".msgid-4").show();
    });
});
</script>

<div>NAME : ABCDEF <button id="btnmsg-1">message</button></div>
    <div class="msgid-1" style="display:none;"><textarea></textarea><input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send"></div>
<div>NAME : GHIJKL <button id="btnmsg-2">message</button></div>
    <div class="msgid-2" style="display:none;"><textarea></textarea><input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send"></div>
<div>NAME : MNOPQR <button id="btnmsg-3">message</button></div>
    <div class="msgid-3" style="display:none;"><textarea></textarea><input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send"></div>
<div>NAME : STUVWX <button id="btnmsg-4">message</button></div>
    <div class="msgid-4" style="display:none;"><textarea></textarea><input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send"></div>
```

if i click button id="btnmsg-1" then div class="msgid-1" show, and then i click button id="btnmsg-3" then div class="msgid-3" show but div class="msgid-1" not hide or close,my question how hide the div if another div is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using separate handlers for each, you can use the related positioning of the elements along with classes to group them to show/hide

ie, Add a class like `btnmsg` to all the buttons and `msgedit` to all the div's that have to be shown/hidden. Now register a click handler to `.btnmsg` elements, from your markup the `.msgedit` element to be shown is the next sibling of the clicked button so show that then hide all other `.msgedit` elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $edits = $('.msgedit')
  $(".btnmsg").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this).parent().next().show();
    $edits.not($this).hide()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>NAME : ABCDEF
  <button class="btnmsg" id="btnmsg-1">message</button>
</div>
<div class="msgid-1 msgedit" style="display:none;">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send" />
</div>
<div>NAME : GHIJKL
  <button class="btnmsg" id="btnmsg-2">message</button>
</div>
<div class="msgid-2 msgedit" style="display:none;">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send" />
</div>
<div>NAME : MNOPQR
  <button class="btnmsg" id="btnmsg-3">message</button>
</div>
<div class="msgid-3 msgedit" style="display:none;">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send" />
</div>
<div>NAME : STUVWX
  <button class="btnmsg" id="btnmsg-4">message</button>
</div>
<div class="msgid-4 msgedit" style="display:none;">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send" />
</div>
```

Comment: work, but why if i use table in the button the div can't show.. like this <div><table>
<tr><td><button class="btnmsg" id="btnmsg-1">Pesan</button><button class="btnau" style="border-radius:0px 8px 8px 0px;">Delete</button></td></tr>
</table></div>

Answer (score 1):

Please add same classes to similar elements, and then use this jQuery code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnmsg").click(function(){
        $(".msgid").hide();
        $(this).parent().next(".msgid").show();
    });
});
```

See the complete DEMO working: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/n5f78kqs/

Comment: work, but why if i use table in the button the div can't show.. like this <div><table> <tr><td><button class="btnmsg" id="btnmsg-1">Pesan</button><button class="btnau" style="border-radius:0px 8px 8px 0px;">Delete</button></td></tr> </table></div>

Answer (score 1):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/misev/3/edit?html,css,js,output)***

- don't use `msgid-1`, `msgid-2` etc... cause it defeats the purpose of classNames. Use only `msg`
- Same goes for your buttons. Remove the buttons IDs. use Class `class="btn"`
- Don't use inline styles. Use `<style>` instead or call-to an external stylesheet.

HTML

```
<div class="btn">
  NAME : ABCDEF <button>message</button>
</div>
<div class="msg">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.msg{
  display:none;
}
```

See how more readable is now your code?
jQuery:

```
var $msg = $(".msg");                                       // Get all .msg DIVs
$(".btn").on("click", "button", function( e ){
    $msg.hide();                                            // Hide all
    $(e.delegateTarget).next().show();                      // Show next
});
```

Comment: work, but why if i use table in the button the div can't show.. like this <div><table> <tr><td><button class="btnmsg" id="btnmsg-1">Pesan</button><button class="btnau" style="border-radius:0px 8px 8px 0px;">Delete</button></td></tr> </table></div>

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah jQuery is all about selectors. See this link: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ find the selectors you need to traverse the DOM in order to reach the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling hide() on the elements you would like to hide.

For example, you would make the following change:

```
// Old
$("#btnmsg-1").click(function(){
    $(".msgid-1").show();
});

//New
$("#btnmsg-1").click(function(){
    $(".msgid-1").show();
    $(".msgid-2").hide();
    $(".msgid-3").hide();
    $(".msgid-4").hide();
});
```

A cleaner way to do this would be to give all of your messages a "message" class, then your onClick handlers would look like this:

```
$("#btnmsg-1").click(function(){
    $("#message").hide();
    $(".msgid-1").show();
});
```

Hope that helps!